# ReadSpeaker broken webpage in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, readspeaker

We're using ReadSpeaker component for the web.
We have a button for start to read, we call it to a function of Readspeaker called `readpage()`) the problem starts when we make click on this button the whole web it breaks, is as if the web changes to pdf file without CSS and the button disappear.

Know What is happen? Sorry for can't explain it well I don't know what'sh happen exactly.

Comment: We can check today that ReadSpeaker break all scripts (JavaScript) from web website, we've scripts for center the web and for create a accordion...

Answer (score 2):

Just find the solution!

http://hldev.readspeaker.com/?faq=how-can-i-prevent-javascript-from-breaking-when-readspeaker-is-active

If you have Javascript content inside the reading area these objects can break when ReadSpeaker is active.
This is because we add temporary HTML code to be able to highlight the content that is going to be read.